# How to make the Constructor theadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Can i make the Constructor of a Class threadsafe? The keyword synchronized is not allowed?
I dont want so make a variable where i safe the "State" of the object and check in every method ..

Example:

```
    public class Main2 {

    static TestClass object;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                object = new TestClass();
            };
        }.start();

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                object.printValue();
            }
        }.start();
    }
}



   class TestClass {

    private int value;

    public TestClass() {
        System.out.println("Start Constructor");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Finished Constructor");

        this.value = 5;
    }

    public void printValue() {
        System.out.println("Value: \"" + this.value + "\"");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Start Constructor
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main2$2.run(Main2.java:19)
Finished Constructor
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Constructor are Thread-Safe because only one thread is allowed to instantiate Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Thread-safety inside your object. The object isn't created before you access it.

You are just accessing a null object. A simple null check will do the trick.

Comment: I know, but then i have to check, if the instance is null in every method and this is a way too much work.

I just want, that the methods wait, until the Object is initialized.

Comment: @ferdinand Vincenzo's answer does not do that. Use a `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: Note that there is no strict _happens-before_ relationship between reference assignment and reference usage by the second thread. The field `object` should be `volatile`, otherwise the second thread might see either `null` or - even worse - a partially constructed object.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Factory pattern.

Make the costructor private and add a public static synchronized method that costruct the object.

like that: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=21